# Printing a report in a WinDEV program, using Wine on OS X

Tags: macos, printing, report, wine, windev

I have a WinDEV program, which can print a report. This works perfectly on Windows. However, I have been asked to make this program work on OS X as well, since we have a few customers that use Apple...

Using Wine, I managed to get the program working. However, I still have one huge issue when printing the report...

For some reason, none of my text fields are printing. Images, background, etc. are fine and perfectly printed, text however is left blank...

I print using the iPrintReport function to print my report. The report contains text in a webfont (Verdana), which is always present at both Windows and Apple... To test, I also put one HTML text, which has been styled to use Arial or Helvetica... Also, for testing purposes, I added the iPreview function before printing the report...

On the screen, the preview is also blank wherever there should be text. If, however, I "save" the preview as either a Word or a HTML file, the text magically appears, while it's only partially there (only the HTML box) when I save it to PDF and absent when I actually print the page...

Does anyone know how I can solve this?
Do you need more information?

Thanks,

Jeroen